# How to load route configuration from server before dependency injection in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-router

My top menu module doesn't know anything about routes and modules, that will be used for menu items before they load from api.

```
var routeConfig = [
            {loadChildren: "./widget1.ts#Widget1Module", path: "widget1.ts"},
            {loadChildren: "./widget2.ts#Widget2Module", path: "widget2.ts"},
            {loadChildren: "./widget3.ts#Widget3Module", path: "widget3.ts"}
      ]; // this must be loaded before AppRoutingModule inject

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routeConfig
    )
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { 
};
```

Now i just use routeConfig as global variable and make request from pure javascript before angular imports module. How to do it correctly?

Comment: parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method

Answer (score 1):

As Gunter said, we can delay bootstrap method and pass some parameters like [that](https://blog.sstorie.com/providing-external-data-when-bootstrapping-angular-2/). But it is a wrong way in my case.
In angular we can redefine routing in our application. So we can leave initialization parameter for RouterModule empty:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot([]), HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But then [redefine](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor) them after web api retrieve us callback with route configuration:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {
  }
  public isLoaded : bool = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('app/routerConfig.json')
               .map((res:any) => res.json())
               .subscribe(data => {
                 this.router.resetConfig(data);
                 this.isLoaded = true;
               }, error => console.log(error));

  }
}
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SRoFPiJzz7AINDRXJz37?p=preview) is an example in Plunker.